# failed to schedual xaction file for run PDI job

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon

I want to run my Pentaho-data-integration job with xaction file.
my job(schedualeJob.kjb) has one transformation(repository2.ktr)( without any schedule).
the contetnt of my  schedule.xaction file is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<action-sequence> 
  <title>My scheduled job</title>
  <version>1</version>
  <logging-level>ERROR</logging-level>
  <documentation> 
    <author>mzy</author>  
    <description>Sequence for running daily job.</description>  
    <help/>  
    <result-type/>  
    <icon/> 
  </documentation>

  <inputs> 
  </inputs>

  <outputs> 
    <logResult type="string">
      <destinations>
        <response>content</response>
      </destinations>
    </logResult>
  </outputs>

  <resources>
    <job-file>
      <solution-file> 
        <location>schedualeJob.kjb</location>  
        <mime-type>text/xml</mime-type> 
      </solution-file>     
    </job-file>
  </resources>

  <actions> 
    <action-definition>
      <component-name>KettleComponent</component-name>
      <action-type>Pentaho Data Integration Job</action-type>
      <action-inputs>   
      </action-inputs>
      <action-resources>
        <job-file type="resource"/>
      </action-resources>
      <action-outputs> 
        <kettle-execution-log type="string" mapping="logResult"/>  
        <kettle-execution-status type="string" mapping="statusResult"/> 
      </action-outputs>   
      <component-definition>
        <kettle-logging-level><![CDATA[info]]></kettle-logging-level>           
      </component-definition>
    </action-definition>

  </actions> 
</action-sequence>
```

I uploaded all of these 3 file in my Pentaho cde repository(beside of my report).
and set schedule for schedule.xaction file from pentaho cde. but the schedule does not run correctly. any body can help me?

Comment: I'am affaid Xaction disapeared from Pentaho in V5 or V6, when they switched to Jackrabbit. Can you access your Pentaho server in SSH ?

Comment: do you have any idea do this work?